# Regex - email regex in google apps script

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

https://regex101.com/r/0HJa24/1

The regular expression is correct on Regex101.

```js
//Google Apps Script
const recipientList    = paramSheet.getRange('C2:C').getValues().map(cell=>cell[0]).filter(cell=>new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}$').test(cell));

function test(){
   console.log(reciveList);
}
```

but when I run test function , result show

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vHWh.png

why

Comment: See linked duplicate above your question. `.-]+\.[` should be `.-]+\\.[`